# How to add variable (with lower dimensionality) to xarray datasets

Tags: python, python-xarray

I couldn't really find the answer in the doc of xarray for my particular struggle. A solution might be helpful to other as well.

So here my issue: **I'm trying to use xarray in a fluid way** like I use to do with nested dictionaries, structuring them according to my experimental protocol: that is **reflecting the raw experimental data labeling**. **Add new variable (with lower dimensionality) on the fly**, derived from raw data **under the same labeling scheme**.

For this example, Let say I have a sample of measurements  represented here:
[image: data representation in excel sheet]

one big matrix with 9 sub-matrices of 36 points each names as follow: a1 b1 c1, row 2: a2, b2, c2, row 3: a3, b3, c3. Each point within a sub-matrix is indexed from row 1 to 6, col 1 to 6.

I have multiple big matrix labeled A, B, C, etc that have the same structure.

The xarray dataset should index the measurement variable 'sag0' by the coordinates : [x y row col]
now I want to add a variable that represent say the average value of all element on an 6x6 array located at [x, y]

I did as follow:

1. load the excel sheet into panda
2. create a set of inner key, outer key
3. create an empty np array whose dimension corresponds to the xarray dimensions
4. load sag0 values into dataset
5. Add a new variable (here's my problem.)

```py
primArray_coord_label = ['A', 'B', 'C']
secdArray_coord_label = [ letter+number for letter in ['a', 'b','c'] for number in ['1', '2', '3']]
lens_number_coord_label = [number for number in np.arange(1,37,1)]
lens_number_coord_array_label = np.reshape(lens_number_coord_label,(6,6))
na = len(primArray_coord_label)
nb = len(secdArray_coord_label)
nc = len(lens_number_coord_label)

# ~~VV~~ we create the multi-dimensional array mirroring the nested dictionnary, 
# it will contain the value of the variable
multidimarray = np.empty((na, nb, 6,6))
for k, outerkey in enumerate(primArray_coord_label):
    for l, innerkey in enumerate(secdArray_coord_label):
        #print(outerkey, innerkey)
        values = nested_dict[outerkey][innerkey]
        # print(outerkey, innerkey, np.shape(values))
        # we create the multi-dimensional array containing the value of the variable
        multidimarray[k][l][:][:] = values

# ~~VV~~ we convert the multi-dimensional array into an xarray using the dictionnary key. 
ds= xr.Dataset({
        'sag0':
        (['x', 'y', 'row', 'col'],
        multidimarray, 
        {'description':'lens sag value after etching', 'units': '$\mum$,'}),
    },coords={
    'x':('x',primArray_coord_label,{'description':'primary zone of 9 matrices on sample'} ),
    'y':('y',secdArray_coord_label, {'description':'ID of one matrix of 36 lens part of a zone'}),
    'row':('row',np.arange(1,7,1)),
    'col':('col',np.arange(1,7,1)),
    }
)
ds
```

so far this looks okay:

[image: data representation in xarray]

I want to add new variables: mean value over a all 36 points of an array
I want it to be accessible with the same coordinate x y...

This is what I tried:

```
def mean_of_array(values):
    return values.mean()

for x in ds['x']:
    for y in ds['y']:
        mean_val=mean_of_array(ds.sag0.sel(x=x, y=y))
        print(mean_val)
        ds = ds.assign(mean_val=mean_val)
ds

<xarray.DataArray 'sag0' ()>
array(49.51944444)
Coordinates:
    x        <U1 'A'
    y        <U2 'a1'
```

but I failed to get it stored in my xarray:
the new variable is there but empty and has no coordinates.

[image: xarray with empty new variable]

How do I do this?? I'm not sure if this is the right approach at all..

Comment: 0 is not the same as empty. I would expect the mean of an array to have no dimensions - what is it that you're expecting? note that there is a big difference between DataArrays (which are only a single array and cannot hold additional variables) and Datasets (~ structured dictionaries of DataArrays). in your code, you assign mean to `ds`, but it looks like `ds` might be a DataArray? Also, `mean_of_array` is not defined in your code. Can you make sure you include a complete example? Read through the guide to developing a [mre] - try especially to make your example more *minimal* for clarity.

Comment: does `ds["mean_val"] = ds.sag0.mean(dim=("row", "col"))` do what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looping over `x` and `y`, you can take the mean over a subset of dimensions by providing a list-like argument for `dims` in any reduction operation, including [`mean`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.mean.html):

```py
ds["mean_val"] = ds.sag0.mean(dim=("row", "col"))
```

See the xarray docs on [aggregation](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/user-guide/computation.html#aggregation) for more information.

Comment: Hello Michael. This indeed solved my issue in an easy and efficient way.

Comment: Now I see how to use xarray in the better way, i.e. not through nested loops as I used to do ! It seems I can apply arbitrary function with the same synthax (c.f. wrapping-custom-computation of the doc). Thank you very much!

Comment: glad this helped! yep, this is much easier to write, read, and also much much higher performance. Happy xarray-ing :)